# Relation between compact Lie group and Lie algebra representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Currently I'm studying representation theory for compact Lie groups and I don't know how to link representations of Lie algebra to representations of corresponding Lie group, ie. suppose I have a decomposition of Lie algebra representation into irreducible subrepresentations and weight spaces. Is induced representation of Lie group decomposed in the same way? What are weights of this representation and do they have something in common with maximal tori weights?